# Pandas - Editing String on a Row and keep headers

Tags: python, pandas

I want to concatenate a string to each row of my dataframe.
On my code i can concatenate but on newdf there is no headers 'Site' and
'Login' anymore.
How can edit the string inside and keep the headers?

Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd
list = pd.read_csv('sites.csv', sep=',')
df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns=['Site', 'Login'])
newdf = df['Site'].map(str) + 'login'
```

Comment: `df['Site'].map(str) + 'login'` would only return the updated series. Not a Dataframe. Did you mean `df['Site'] = df['Site'].map(str) + 'login'` or `newdf = df.assign(Site=df['Site'].map(str) + 'login')`?

Comment: @HenryEcker  thank u! 
newdf = df.assign(Site=df['Site'].map(str) + 'login') is what i was looking for.